# How to use JSR 303 @Valid annotation to validate primitive types?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, validation

JSR 303 @Valid annotation can be used to validate input objects to a controller method, as demonstrated [on Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)

Is it possible to use @Valid annotation to validate primitive types like int and long[]? If so, how?

Here is an example Spring MVC method signature that needs to be validated that the parameters are above 0:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/delete" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView deleteBulk(@RequestParam("userId") int userId, @RequestParam("ids") long[] ids) {
```

Comment: `long[]` is not a primitive type

Comment: Why don't you try it? Look at the javadoc of the annotation you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't be done. It's for *bean* validation, as described [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303#2).

Answer (score 2):

you can validate @RequestParam/@PathVariable simple objects and primitives, if put **@Validated on full controller**.

And if you don't use spring-boot, you should declare MethodValidationPostProcessor by yourself

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```